# VS2013 std::function with member function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, std-function, member-functions

I'm trying to use std::function with member functions like this:

```
struct Foo
{
   void bar(int) const { /* ... */ }
};

//later on
std::function<void(const Foo&, int)> fun = &Foo::bar;
```

This works under GCC 4.8.1 but fails to compile under VS2013 with the following error:

```
error C2664: 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,const Foo &,int>::_Set(std::_Func_base<_Ret,const Foo &,int> *)' :
cannot convert argument 1 from '_Myimpl *' to 'std::_Func_base<_Ret,const Foo &,int> *'
```

It looks to me like a bug in VS but maybe I'm not seeing something? Is there a way to workaround it (without external libs like boost)?

**Edit:** I forgot "const" in bar signature. But this still doesn't work in VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::function` is required to accept pointers to member functions (definition of *`INVOKE`*).

The simplest workaround is to use `std::mem_fn` instead, or wrap the constructor argument with `std::mem_fn`:

```
std::function<void(const Foo&, int)> fun = std::mem_fn(&Foo::bar);
```